# React router state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a [simple code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-elion-m3q93?file=/src/App.js). I am using react-router and I can't get why the state of all pages are fixed to the one of the initial render and the inputfields share all the value?

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Page from "./Page";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      <Link to="/users">Users</Link>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/about">
          <Page direction="left" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/users">
          <Page direction="right" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <Page direction="up" />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

export default function Page({direction}){
  let reducer = (state, action) => state;
  let [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {direction});
  return (<div><input type="text"/>{state.direction}</div>)
}
```

Comment: The code on given link is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64076982/6094348) has provided a solution, i think its missing an explanation of the cause of the issue.

#### Problem:

So the problem is because of how React updates the UI in an optimized way. In your case, React is re-using your `Page` component. Because `Page` component is already in the DOM, instead of creating a new one, React re-uses the same instance of the `Page` component and only changes the data that has changed, in your case, only `direction` prop changes.

Adding the `key` prop works because this allows React to differentiate between different instances of `Page` component.

#### Alternative Solution:

When React re-uses the `Page` component, uderlying instance of the `Page` component stays the same but the different `props` are passed to the underlying instance.

In your code, since you are not updating the state when `direction` prop changes, you don't see a different state value.

To fix this, you can use `useEffect` hook that dispatches an action to update the state whenever `direction` prop changes.

Changing the code in `Page.js` file as shown below will fix the problem:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "DIRECTION_CHANGE":
      return { ...state, direction: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default function Page({ direction }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { direction });

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "DIRECTION_CHANGE", payload: direction });
  }, [direction]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
      {JSON.stringify(state)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

For further details, see: [`React - Reconciliation`](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#component-elements-of-the-same-type)

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by adding a property `key` to each `Page` component

```js
<Switch>
  <Route  path="/about">
    <Page key="/about" direction="left" />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/users">
    <Page key="/users"  direction="right" />
  </Route>
  <Route  path="/">
    <Page key="/" direction="up" />
  </Route>
</Switch>;
```

This way you will exploit the diffing algorithms https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys

Comment: Weird behavior, I was thinking that react does this automatically. Well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me for your Page component:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Page(props) {

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
      {JSON.stringify(props)}
    </div>
  );
}
```